# Merging txt files matchs conditions

Tags: python, list, file, text, merge

I have a list of files in txt format in a Python in my app like this:

```
['Pr00-1.txt', '900-2.txt', 'Pr00-2.txt', '900-1.txt', 'Pr900-3.txt', '00-3.txt']
```

I'm trying to merge all `00` files `['Pr00-1.txt', 'Pr00-2.txt', '00-3.txt']` in one `00.txt` file.

Same to 900 files and so on regardless on `Pr` or `-*.txt`, `*` is the number.
I tried using split but it's not helping.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Please [edit] and post what you have tried already in your question, and what do you mean about *merge* ? Just append all `00` files into the `00.txt`?

Comment: Stackoverflow is *NOT* a consulting website. Try something and come back with the problem you encounter, if any.

Comment: Why are you using Python?  This sounds like a simple command in your command shell.  If you *do* have to use Python, please show the code and explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: @hakam-omran You says you tried using `split`, what happened? How did you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is essentially what you want.  Find the 00 files with a regular expression then open 00.txt and write all those files to it.  Note that this solution isn't generalized for any xx pattern, and also it fails if one of the files doesn't exist.  I'll leave the rest up to you.

```
import re

with open('00.txt.', 'w') as outfile:
    filenames = ['Pr00-1.txt', '900-2.txt', 'Pr00-2.txt', '900-1.txt', 
        'Pr900-3.txt', '00-3.txt']
    for filename in filenames:
        match = re.search(r'(^|[^0-9])00.*.txt', filename)
        if (match):
            with open(filename) as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
```